# Rename pstree tag to pst-tree

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

The [pstree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pstree) tag is ill-named, since it is the name of a command defined by the `pst-tree` package rather than the package name.  I suggest that the [pst-tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pst-tree) tag replace the [pstree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pstree) tag (perhaps leaving the latter as a synonym).

There are at the moment 8 questions with the tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I renamed [pstree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pstree) to [pst-tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pst-tree) and kept [pstree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pstree) as a synonym, because it's a bit different and possibly it could be used again, as it's the name of a command, as Alan said.